# Why Google Maps v2 are Blank on Android emulator?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I am creating a new Maps Activity using Android Studio and following all steps, with adding an API_KEY, to manifest, enabling Android Maps API in Google console, and restricting it to my package and SHA1. I have searched all internet and tried many things, but the Map is still blank.

Can anyone help?

Comment: you run debug or get release and install it?

Comment: do you have play services on the emulator? If you using release sha1 key you can't use debug build variant

Answer (score 0):

Blank screen means you have problem about Google Maps API signing.

Probably you have created a new keystore file and used its SHA for enabling maps API.

But while you are developing all your runs are signed with debug.keystore which is default unless you declare one.

You can use your keystore file that created by you for debug runs from **signing configs** in Project Settings from Android Studio.

Good luck

Emre